# How to keep correct layout for UIStackView's subview after the subview re-appears after device rotation?

Tags: ios

Hi have a `UIStackView` for which I have deselected the Installed property for compact heights:

[image]

Interface Builder shows the element in portrait mode and hides the element in landscape mode. When I run the app in the iPhone simulator, initially in portrait mode the element is rendered correctly (second row of buttons):

[image]

The element disappears after rotating right. But after rotating left again back to portrait mode, the element is rendered incorrectly (see top left of the screen):

[image]

Do I need to programmatically take care of the element's layout after is appears again? If so, where can I find documentation to help get me started with this?

Comment: You say it “disappears”. Where does it go? How do you make it disappear?
 Are you setting its `hidden` property?

Comment: @robmayoff I don't know where it goes :-) What I did was introduce a variation for compact height, and deselect the checkbox for the "installed" property for that variation (using the Attributes inspector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing the parent view's `subviews` and `arrangedSubviews` properties indicates that iOS adds the view to the former, but not to the latter. (This is when iOS takes care of adaptive layout based on variations of the 'installed' checkbox for different traits, as specified in the attribute inspector.)

So this specific subview needs to be inserted back into the arranged subviews. I added this override to the main view controller (`layout` is the stack view, `secondaryRow` is the row of buttons that is removed/added depending on the screen's height):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if let index = layout.subviews.index(of: secondaryRow) {
        layout.insertArrangedSubview(secondaryRow, at: index)
    }
}
```

I'm sure it can be generalised, perhaps to synchronise all `UIStackView`s `subviews` and `arrangedSubviews` when the layout has changed.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to redraw the views again when you change the orientation by overriding `viewWillTransistion` method.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    // When orientations changes draw the layout again
    // by invalidating the current layout of the views
    // For Example, if I want to redraw for UIStackView I will use
    stackView.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Comment: `UIStackView` does not have an `invalidateLayout()` method. I dragged an `@IBOutlet` for the stack view to my view controller, and I added an override for `viewWillTransition` to my view controller, but Xcode doesn't show the `invalidateLayout()` method on the stack view variable, and I can't find it in Apple's documentation either.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Basically for other views `setNeedsLayout` method need to called.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't resolve the problem. I tried calling `setNeedsLayout()` on either the row stack view as well as its parent stack view. Is this problem a common problem that may have been documented elsewhere?

Comment: The problem is related to redrawing the views when orientation changes. Haven't used `UIStackView` much. It must have related methods to resolve it. Maybe you can try `layoutIfNeeded()`. If still, it doesn't work then there is some other issue.